# Using Xpath to get text from span- webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver to get some text on my webpage using xpath.

This is the code

```
<a class="ng-binding" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabCreatedByMe">
                            Created By Me                              
<span class="badge ng-binding">3</span>
</a>
```

I need to get the number '3'. this number is changing everytime

I made this code but it does not return anything

```
public String getAmountSubtab1() throws InterruptedException{
    WebElement s =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='badge ng-binding']"));
    return s.getText(); }
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You mean `s.getText` returns nothing? If you change it to a `.findElements`, and check the size of the collection that is returned, how many elements does it have? What if you make your XPath more targetted? `//span[@class='badge ng-binding']`

Comment: When you say it returns nothing, does that mean you get null? Or do you see any NoSuchElementExceptions?
Also, use of Xpath is not advisable. I would suggest you to use CSS selectors.

Comment: Are you using IE? For that case, as Arran said, driver.findElement(...) does not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have only one span with the class badge ng-binding It might be that you might have another span before this with the same class name. Advised not to use class name when identifying an element. Use this xpath. Should work.

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Created By Me')]/span
```